# access store outside of component vuejs

Tags: ecmascript-6, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have a file for configuring my OpenID Connect authentication

```
export const authMgr = new Oidc.UserManager({
  userStore: new Oidc.WebStorageStateStore(),
  authority: **appsetting.oidc**
})
```

I want to access my state in order to get the value of appsetting.

I did this:

```
import store from './store'

const appsetting = () => store.getters.appsetting
```

but my appsetting is always returning undefined

what I my missing?

Store:

app.js

```
const state = {
  appsetting: appsetting,
}

export {
  state 
}
```

getters.js

```
const appsetting = state => state.appsetting

export {
  appsetting
}
```

index.js

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  actions,
  getters,
  modules: {
    app
  },
  strict: debug,
  plugins: [createLogger]
})
```

when I print the value of `store.getters`, it returns this:

```
{
  return __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__store__["a" /* default */].getters;
}
```

No the actual store objects

Comment: Is `appsetting` getter is a part of any store module?

Comment: Yes, it is part of the module

Comment: Can you post your store module?

Comment: How do you import in `index.js`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [accessing vuex store in js file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47819289/accessing-vuex-store-in-js-file)

Comment: You probably have an index.js/main.js file in you /store folder. You want to import that:
import store from './store/index' then it should work.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Try to import 'store' with curly brackets

```
import {store} from '../store/index'

store.getters.appSettings
```

Another option is to access from the vue property

```
import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.store.getters.appSettings
```

Comment: An example of how to access a nested module's getter (and also pass a parameter) is `const hasTextAutomationEnabled = store.getters['account/hasFeature']('text-automation');`

(You can normally use the dot notation, but since the module is referenced with a forward-slash "/", it's easier to get the property via the array syntax with square brackets. If there is no parameter for your getter, don't put the "(param)" at the end.)

Comment: Anyone can explain why we need to use curly brackets?

Comment: The curly brackets around store are used because it's not a default export. If it's a default export then you don't use the curly brackets. In this example OP used export { store } instead of export default store

Comment: The first one works great, but the `Vue.store.getters.appSettings` one doesn't seem to work for me, weird...

Comment: both doesnt work on my case.. I have a modules in my store,,, but accessing them gives error,,, I tried both options above but doesnt work, im using typescript

Comment: Isn't this going to make it not reactive? How do you use `store.getters` outside of `export default {}` and at the same time make sure that it is reactive?

Answer (score 1):

As for 2023 accesing store with

```
import {store} from '../store/index'
store.getters.appSettings
```

wasnt working for me but after removing curly brackets like so:

```
import store from '../store/index'
store.getters.appSettings
```

It started working as intended

Comment: I think this works only because your store is the default export. Otherwise, the curly brackets are needed as stated by Jack Barry in the accepted answer.