# accessing vuex store in js file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Just like in main.js, I'm trying to access my store from a helper function file:

```
import store from '../store'

let auth = store.getters.config.urls.auth
```

But it logs an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getters' of undefined.

I have tried

```
this.$store.getters.config.urls.auth
```

Same result.

store:

```
//Vuex
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex);

const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        config: 'config',

    },
    getters: {
        config: state => state.config
    },
});

export default store
```

How do I make my store available outside of components?

Comment: I have seen some related issues due to old syntax with new version. I think answer given is checked in latest version.

Comment: how about writing a pure function that takes the `store` getter as a function parameter? then pass the `store` to the function when you are using it in Vue component

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```
import store from '../store'

store.getters.config
// => 'config'
```

Comment: store is undefined

Comment: It worked for me. Just tried it on my repo. And yes, you have to use `getters` if you access store outside of Vue.

Comment: Yes, just looking at it, it should work, but for some very weird reason it is not working.

Comment: I would double check if your path to `store.js` is correct in your project.

Comment: This can lead to unexpected behaviour though. For example for me, when a user first logs in, this just yields undefined in the .js file, but Vuex shows it is clearly defined.

Comment: how to watch changes like using watchers?

Answer (score 10):

If you are using namespaced modules, you might encounter the same difficulties I had while trying to retrieve items from the store;

what might work out for you is to specify the namespace while calling the getters (example bellow)

```js
import store from '../your-path-to-your-store-file/store.js'

console.log(store.getters.['module/module_getter']);

// for instance

console.log(store.getters.['auth/data']);
```

Comment: ```javascript
console.log(store.getters) // returns all getters from vuex, may help while debugging.
```

Comment: This worked for me:  store.getters['auth/data']. No "period" after getters

Answer (score 9):

## This Worked For Me In 2021

I tried a bunch of different things and it seems, at least in Vue 3, that this works. Here is an example store:

```
export default {
  user: {
    bearerToken: 'initial',
  },
};
```

Here is my `Getters` file:

```
export default {
  token: (state) => () => state.user.bearerToken,
};
```

Inside your `.js` file add the page to your `store\index.js` file.

```
import store from '../store';
```

In order to access the getters just remember it is a function (which may seem different when you use `mapGetters`.)

```
console.log('Checking the getters:', store.getters.token());
```

The state is more direct:

```
console.log('Checking the state:', store.state.user.bearerToken);
```

Comment: Does this still work in 2022?

Comment: @BeastJulian it should, that was a year ago and Vue 3 is till current. Try it.

Answer (score 3):

put brackets on your import and it should work

```
import { store } from '../store'
```

Comment: Why put brackets? It has a default export.

Answer (score 3):

using this approach has worked for me:

```
// app.js
import store from "./store/index"

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    store, //vuex
});
window.App = app;


// inside your helper method
window.App.$store.commit("commitName" , value);
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are using nuxt you can use this approach

```
window.$nuxt.$store.getters.myVar
```

if you have multiple modules

```
window.$nuxt.$store.getters['myModule/myVar']
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone like me is trying to do this in Pinia, and following the docs doesn't work for you, here's what worked for me. This doesn't make sense to me but it works so I'm going with it, if anyone knows why this works please let me know.

Here is the Pinia store:

```
//Pinia
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const store = defineStore('test', {
    state: () => ({
        config: 'config'
    })
})
```

Here is the logic that accesses the store

```
// function.js
import { store } from '../store'

store().config
```

Typically, you would import the store and then initiate it as a function, as per the Pinia Docs.

```
import { store } from '../store'

const testStore = store()
```

However, this doesn't work and will say you forgot to install Pinia.