# accessing vuex store's state in .js file

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

auth.js

```
export default {
state: {
    token: localStorage.getItem('token') || null,
},
getters: {
    authToken: state => state.token,
},
```

store.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import auth from './modules/auth'
Vue.use(Vuex)

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    auth,
   },
})
```

Now I wanted to get `token` from any `.js` file. I tried as following but I am getting `cannot read property state of undefined`. If I use `getter` then error is `cannot read property getters of undefined`

config.js

```
import  {store}  from '../../store/store'

// const token = store.getters.authToken;
 const token = store.state.auth.token;
```

File structure:

```
src/
   services/
           config/
              config.js
   store/
      modules/
            auth.js
      store.js
```

Edit:

```
 warning  in ./src/services/config/config.js

"export 'default' (imported as 'store') was not found in 
'../../store/store'
```

Comment: That error means that you aren't importing that `store` object correctly so it's resolving to `undefined`. Are you sure that the path is `../../store/store`? And are you sure that that `config.js` file is what is throwing the error?

Comment: @thanksd I am sure the path is correct and the error is from `config.js`, I have added some `warnings`

Comment: Hmm, not sure then. Although I would expect that `export 'default' (imported as 'store')` error to only occur if you were trying to import it via `import store from ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this answer from 2017, it's simple and straight-forward. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47819446/7617726

Remember to use a default export