# How watch global variable in component vuejs?

Tags: vue.js

I need global variables for errors. But I don't want set input variable for every component.
How I can watch $errors in component ABC without input variable?

```
(without <abc :errors="$errors"></abc>)
```

index.js:

```
Vue.prototype.$errors = {};

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    render: h => h(App),
}
```

App.vue:

```
...
name: 'App',
components: {
ABC
}
...
methods:{
getContent() {
this.$errors = ...from axis...
}
```

Component ABC:

```
<template>
<div>{{ error }}</div>
</template>
...
watch: {
???
}
```

Comment: Check out vuex - kinda does this

Answer (score 13):

Here's an example of how it could be done:

```js
const errors = Vue.observable({ errors: {} })

Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$errors', {
  get () {
    return errors.errors
  },
  
  set (value) {
    errors.errors = value
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  methods: {
    newErrors () {
      // Generate some random errors
      const errors = {}
      
      for (const property of ['name', 'type', 'id']) {
        if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
          errors[property] = 'Invalid value'
        }
      }
      
      this.$errors = errors
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app2',
  
  watch: {
    $errors () {
      console.log('$errors has changed')
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <pre>{{ $errors }}</pre>
  <button @click="newErrors">New errors</button>
</div>

<div id="app2">
  <pre>{{ $errors }}</pre>
</div>
```

I've created two Vue instances to illustrate that the value really is shared. Clicking the button in the first instance will update the value of `$errors` and the `watch` is triggered in the second instance.

There are a few tricks in play here.

Firstly, reactivity can only track the reading and writing of properties of an observable object. So the first thing we do is create a suitable object:

```js
const errors = Vue.observable({ errors: {} })
```

We then need to wire this up to `Vue.prototype.$errors`. By defining a `get` and `set` for that property we can proxy through to the underlying property within our observable object.

All of this is pretty close to how `data` properties work behind the scenes. For the `data` properties the observable object is called `$data`. Vue then uses `defineProperty` with `get` and `set` to proxy though from the Vue instance to the `$data` object, just like in my example.

Comment: Excellent answer! It helped me a lot with a different problem but requiring a global property.

Comment: Thank you. It works.  by default,  vue can only watch `this.$errors = errors`, can not watch `this.$errors.num = 3` .    use   "deep: true" allow vue to watch deep.

Answer (score 3):

1. as `Estradiaz` said:
   You can use Vuex and access the value outside of Vue like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47575742/10219239
2. This is an addition to `Skirtles` answer:
   You can access such variables via `Vue.prototype.variable`.
   You can set them directly, or use Vue.set, it works either way.

My code (basically the same as `Skirtles`s):
main.js

```
const mobile = Vue.observable({ mobile: {} });
Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$mobile', {
  get() { return mobile.mobile; },
  set(value) { mobile.mobile = value; }
});

function widthChanged() {
  if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
    if (!Vue.prototype.$mobile) Vue.set(Vue.prototype, '$mobile', true);
  } else if (Vue.prototype.$mobile) Vue.set(Vue.prototype, '$mobile', false);
}

window.addEventListener("resize", widthChanged);

widthChanged();
```

Home.vue:

```
watch: {
  '$mobile'(newValue) {
    // react to Change in width
  }
}
```