# "this is undefined" in vue function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Yes, there are a lot of post like this, but i can't figure out whats happening (look for a lot of post here and in Google).

I made my interceptor like this, but I'm getting a message "This is undefined".

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(undefined, function(err) {

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

        if (err.request.status === 401 && err.config && !err.config.__isRetryRequest) {

            console.log('Disconnected. Session expires')

            this.$store.dispatch('logout')
            this.$router.push({ name: "login" });

        }

        throw err;

    });
```

First I had "() => {}" and I have changed to "function() {}", but same error.

How can I do to clear my code?

Comment: try setting var _this = this, and then accessing it as _this.  To verify if it is really this that is causing the problem.  ()=>{} should have worked fine

Comment: Just import your `store` and `router` from their respective files, eg `import store form 'path/to/store` and use `store.dispatch()`. Same thing with `router`

Answer (score 2):

`this` only work in vue components, I suspect your code in question is not in any component. Then you need to look for how to access store and router outside components: [access store outside of component vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47571543/access-store-outside-of-component-vuejs#47575742)

Comment: Thanks. This I have to change the store and router params.